# issue with setInterval loop stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I know this is probably the completely wrong approach, but here is my code:

```
<script>
function dodat(){
var btn=document.createElement("div");
btn.style.width="25px";
btn.style.height="25px";
btn.style.backgroundColor="red";
btn.style.boxShadow="inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
btn.style.position="absolute";
btn.style.left="0px";
math = Math.random();
btn.id=math;
num = 0;
setInterval('var num = num+1;document.getElementById(math).style.left=num;', '10');

document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}
</script>

<body>

<div style="background-color:#c3c3c3;width:500px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;" id="track"></div>
</body>

<script>
setInterval("dodat();", "2000");
</script>
```

I want a continuous flow of red blobs moving forward, but no, they stop when a new one is created.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why did you tag this with jQuery if you don't seem to be using jQuery?

Comment: It should be 'setInterval(dodat, '2000');'

Comment: *"they stop when a new one is created"* Because you are only moving the one whose ID is stored in `math`. Since `math` only holds one value, you are always going to move the last created element. The problem is that you are using global variables and pass strings to `setInterval`. You should restructure the code so that each invocation of `dodat` kind of creates its own context with the state of the created element.

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval loop isn't stopping, it's putting the newly defined box on top of the previous box because you've given them all the same `left` values.(`num` is reset to 0 every time)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Rk97f/1/)

Just setting up a counter(and incrementing it when a new box is added) that modifies the `left` value would fix this.

Edit: Ideally you shouldn't use `position` for this, just floating the divs would do.

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Rk97f/2/)

```
function dodat(){
var btn=document.createElement("div");
btn.style.width="25px";
btn.style.height="25px";
btn.style.backgroundColor="red";
btn.style.boxShadow="inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
btn.style.float="left";
document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}
```